# Angular Interceptor to handle 401 token by refresh token and request all field

Tags: angular, refresh-token, angular-http-interceptors

i have token that expire after specifc time i need to request the token then add the new one to the perviouse filed multi request what happen with me now token request with the same number of 401 api filed and the filed request not called with the new token returned

```ts
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService, private headerRequestService: HeaderRequestService) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
            if ([401, 403].includes(err.status) && this.authenticationService.tokenValue) {

                this.getRefreshToken(request, next);
            }

            const error = (err && err.error && err.error.message) || err.statusText;
            console.error(err);
            return throwError(error);
        }))
    }

    async getRefreshToken(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        await this.authenticationService.refreshToken()
        console.log(this.headerRequestService.addHeader(request))
        return next.handle(this.headerRequestService.addHeader(request));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed and await and return:

```js
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
        if ([401, 403].includes(err.status) && this.authenticationService.tokenValue) {

            return await this.getRefreshToken(request, next);
        }

        const error = (err && err.error && err.error.message) || err.statusText;
        console.error(err);
        return throwError(error);
    }))
}

async getRefreshToken(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    await this.authenticationService.refreshToken()
    console.log(this.headerRequestService.addHeader(request))
    return next.handle(this.headerRequestService.addHeader(request));

}
```